# Pandas Apply Values Based On Grouping Field

Tags: python, pandas, greatest-n-per-group

I have a data frame that looks like:

```
time    action    value
10:00   FG2       2
10:00   Assist    0
09:45   Turnover  -1
09:45   Steal     0
09:30   FG3       3
09:20   Miss      0
```

How can SUM up the value column per `time` and apply it to other rows that share the same `time` value? In this example, the `value` for the second row would be 2, since it shares the same `time` as row one.

Expected output would be:

```
10:00   FG2          2
10:00   Assist       2
09:45   Turnover     -1
09:45   Steal        -1
09:30   FG3          3
09:20   Miss         0
```

The way I would approach it now would be to create a grouped data frame with MAX `value` by `time` and then JOIN back to the original data frame on `time`, but this is SQL/RDBMS-type thinking, and I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this through Python?

For example, in T-SQL, I would write this as `SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY time)`

Comment: Your example is inconsistent with the description at 9:45

Comment: @Randy that is true, just fixed it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what the selection logic is, but here's an example that just takes the first value for each time and propagates it. You could also do something like `.max()`  if you want the largest value:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
    time    action  value
0  10:00       FG2      2
1  10:00    Assist      0
2  09:45  Turnover     -1
3  09:45     Steal      0
4  09:30       FG3      3
5  09:20      Miss      0

In [13]: df['value'] = df['time'].map(df.groupby("time")['value'].first())

In [14]: df
Out[14]:
    time    action  value
0  10:00       FG2      2
1  10:00    Assist      2
2  09:45  Turnover     -1
3  09:45     Steal     -1
4  09:30       FG3      3
5  09:20      Miss      0
```

EDIT: For sum, just replace the inside of the call to `.map` with `df.groupby("time")['value'].sum()`

Comment: I edited my questions for clarity, really it is taking the sum per timestamp

Comment: Added an edit - just a small change to get the sum instead.